# SEO СЕО что мне делать дальше

Tags: оптимизация, оптимизация-сайтов

я в сео не очень шарю, знаю только из интернета. У меня есть сайт (интернет-магазин), я его максимально оптимизировал для сео, он уже у меня выходит на 1-2 странице поиска, но в конце. Вопрос у меня такой, для определенной категории товаров я сделал описание, купил ссылки. Что мне делать дальше и как улучшить позицию именно этой категории? Новое описание писать нет смысла, кажется, и ссылки докупать тоже не очень полезно.

Comment: 100 статей по SEO (2010-2015)  http://coderhs.com/archive/100-seo-articles

 Чек-листы по SEO http://coderhs.com/archive/seo-check-lists

Comment: спасибо, что направил

Comment: >>>> Пожалуйста)